# Build failing on simple java app

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to go through this Heroku tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java

When I try and build the app by running 'mvn package'. Here is the output I get: http://pastie.org/8263477

Looks like its dying on the annotation in line 9 which is...@Override. Looks like a need a newer 'source' but I'm not sure what that is. I'm running Java 1.6.

Comment: If you push it up to the cloud does it run appropriately? This will tell you if it's a problem with your app configuration or if it's with your environment setup.

Comment: Seems to be some baloney in the log output about `-source 1.3`. Is there an incorrect configuration somewhere specifying Java 1.3 perhaps?

Comment: I'd like to build it with maven first so I can run/test it locally. Nothing specifying Java 1.3 that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the maven compiler plugin uses  `-source 1.3`. This can happen when the compiler plugin is configured wrong or maybe an old compiler plugin is used where the default was 1.3. In newer versions it should be 1.5.

Try to add the following to your pom.xml in the plugin section:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If this did not help check what Java and Maven version is used on the command line and post it here please:

```
java -version
mvn -v
```

Also it could help to check the effective pom generated:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```